# I need to generate waveform as shown. in verilog code

Tags: verilog

I need to generate a waveform, as shown in the image. But with my code, I did not get expected waveform

In the design, part got the last and valid values in a random period from test-bench.
my problem is why the I value incremented at valid not equal to one

Design code:

```
module design_d(clk,valid,last,data);

   input clk,valid,last;
   output reg [7:0] data;

     reg [7:0] i; 
     initial
       begin
       data=0;
       i=0;
      end

always @(posedge clk,valid)
    begin

   if (valid)
   begin
     data<=i;
     i=i+1;
     $display("i=%d data=%d ",i,data);
   end
   else 
     begin
       data <=8'bz; 
     end
    end
endmodule
```

Test bench  code:

```
module test;

  reg clk,valid,last;
  wire [7:0] data;

  parameter clk_period=2;

  design_d dut(clk,valid,last,data);

  initial
  begin
    clk=1;
    valid=1;
    last=0;
  end

  always #(clk_period/2) clk=~clk;

  always @(posedge clk)
  begin 
    last=0;
    #4 last=1;
    #clk_period last=0;
    #8 last=1;
    #clk_period last=0;
    #10 last=1;
    #clk_period last=0;
    #16last=1;
    #clk_period last=0;  

    #20 last=1;
    #clk_period last=0;
  end

  always @(posedge clk or last)
  begin
     valid<=1;
     wait(last==1)
     #clk_period;
     valid<=0;
     #clk_period;
     valid<=1;
  end

  initial
  begin 
     $dumpfile("dump.vcd");
     $dumpvars(1);
     #24 $finish;
  end
endmodule
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have difficulties with the English language, which is not your fault but because of that, I may interpret your question wrongly.

You have a waveform of what you need to achieve. This to me suggest that this is a school assignment and therefore I will treat it that way. This means I will **not* give you a complete answer but give you pointers about where you are going wrong. (This should all be in a comment but there is now way it would fit).

> ...got the last and valid values in a random period from test-bench.

First thing to realize is writing a test-bench is just as difficult, if not more difficult then writing the RTL code itself.

In your test-bench You are using `always @(posedge clk)` but inside that section you use `#...` statements. That by itself is not wrong. Dangerous, yes, but not necessary wrong.

**But**
Your clock has  a time period of 2 (`parameter clk_period=2;`) and inside your posedge clock you use delays which are **equal or bigger** then the clock period. That often leads to a disaster, as you have found out.
Read up on how Verilog works, especially when the sensitivity list `always @...` is used: It is not triggered until all statement in the section have been dealt with. In your case it means the that it will takes several clock edges until the always block is started again.

**Test Bench**
I don't know what the assignment was so I'll use the waveform you have given. 
As `last` and `valid` are inputs to you module I will give you pointers how to make those.

`valid` is high for 4 clock cycles, it is then low for one clock cycle, after which it repeats itself. This means you need a pattern which repeats itself every 5 clock cycles and thus you need to make a counter which counts 0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4,...

You should **not** make that using `#.....` statements. You should use the test bench clock and make a counter which counts!
Making a counter which counts as described above is the first thing you need to learn in HDL! You will find that you have to do that over and over and over and over .. In every piece of RTL code and every test bench.

**Modulo 5 counter.**

I prefer for all my modules and my test benches to have a reset. 
If only that it allows me to start a new test from a known state.

```
reg [2:0] counter;

always @(posedge clk or negedge reset_n)
begin
   if (reset_n)
      counter <= ...
   else // clocked section
   begin
      if (..)
        counter <= ...
      else       
        counter <= ...
   end
end
```

Start fresh and get the above code running first. Observe that the counter is indeed running 0,1 2, 3, 4, 0, .. before you continue.

**Derived signals .**
Next learn to derive signals from that.
Basic rule: in a clocked section, if you need a signal at counter value X you have to generate that at cycle X-1.

Thus to make last high when the counter is 3 you have to set that up when the counter is 2:

```
always @(posedge clk...
...
   if (counter==3'h2)
      last <= 1'b1;
   else
      last <= 1'b0;
```

I leave making the valid to you.

Once you got your test bench running start working on your design_d module.

Some tips:

- Use always non-blocking assignments `<=` in your clocked section. **
- Do NOT use a clock period of 2, use 100 or 1000. You will find out in due time why that is better.
- Do not use `always @(posedge clk or [one or more signals] )` unless as per my example. **
- Take care of your indenting. I had to do some mayor editing on your code.

<sup>**</sup><sub>Sorry I can't go into details why that is good practice most of the time as that would triple the size of this answer. For now please follow the tips.</sub>

I could have written the actual code in a tenth of the time it took me to write all that so I hope you will not delete the question as others may profit from it.